# Compare list of information with other Lists SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

[image: SQL]

This is the database.

1. autorizacao_procedimento.tipo can be P or N
2. procedimento.tipo can be A or F

### Rules

Each autorizacao has 4 lists:

1. A list of procedimento.tipo = A, that must be of procedimento.tipo = (1*)
2. A list of procedimento.tipo = A, that must not have procedimento.tipo = N (2*)
3. A list of procedimento.tipo = F, that must be of procedimento.tipo = P (1*)
4. A list of procedimento.tipo = F, that must not have procedimento.tipo = N  (2*)

*1* A solicitacao must have all procedimentos specified to be valid.
2* A solicitacao must not have any procedimentos to be valid*

Those relations are built-in table autorizacao_procedimento
The table solicitacao_procedimento makes the relations between solicitacao and procedimento.

---

**What I need to do?**
I need to find a list of autorizacao that match with the solicitacao by codigo following the rules.

This is one of my attempts:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( select a.id, p.id as procedimentoId, p.codigo, p.tipo as procedimentoTipo, ap.tipo as autorizacaoProcedimentoTipo
       from autorizacao_2.autorizacao a
                inner join autorizacao_2.autorizacao_procedimento ap on a.id = ap.autorizacao_id
                inner join autorizacao_2.procedimento p on ap.procedimento_id = p.id where a.id = 12 order by a.id, p.tipo, ap.tipo) AS cf
         left join autorizacao_2.solicitacao_procedimento sp on sp.procedimento_id = cf.procedimentoId
         left join autorizacao_2.solicitacao s on sp.solicitacao_id = s.id
where s.id = '24'
```

Here I was trying to get all procedimentos of the autorizacao and compare it with the autorizacao in the solicitacao.

I'm doing this in a Springboot / SpringData Jpa application.
I created a repository custom to use criteria with native query.

This is how the data is:
[image]

Comment: For a hands-on SQL question, which is what your question looks to be, you would have a much easier time getting help here if you instead phrase the question by showing sample input data for all tables involved, along with the expected output.

Comment: What does this have to do with `java` or `jpa`?

Comment: I need to do this search o a Java/JPA and Springboot application.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: If you need to do this in JPA (or other obfuscation layers), then the `sql` tag should be removed (and replaced with e.g. `hql`)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id as autorizacaoId
from autorizacao_2.autorizacao a
         inner join autorizacao_2.autorizacao_procedimento ap on a.id = ap.autorizacao_id
where (ap.tipo = 'P'
    and ap.procedimento_id not in (select sp.procedimento_id
                                   from autorizacao_2.solicitacao s
                                            inner join autorizacao_2.solicitacao_procedimento sp on s.id = sp.solicitacao_id
                                   where s.id = 1941))
   OR (ap.tipo = 'U' and ap.procedimento_id in (select sp.procedimento_id
                                                from autorizacao_2.solicitacao s
                                                         inner join autorizacao_2.solicitacao_procedimento sp on s.id = sp.solicitacao_id
                                                where s.id = 1941))
group by a.id;
```

I found this solution but I'm not sure about the performance.
This solution returns the autorizacao that doesn't match with the solicitacao.
**Now, I'm trying to find a way to return only autorizacao that matches.**